# How to enable per-site templates within Mezzanine multi-tenancy

Tags: django, mezzanine, multi-tenant

We're expanding our business into Europe and I'm using Mezzanine's multi-tenancy feature to host both the US and EU versions of the site on the same Django installation. We have a `/locations` page on each site that I would like to serve with different templates, based on the `SITE_ID`.

I've followed Mezzanine's sparse documentation [here](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/multi-tenancy.html) and added the following to `settings.py`

```
HOST_THEMES = [
    ('domain.com', 'domain_app'), 
    ('domain.eu', 'domain_eu')
]
```

I've added `domain_eu` to `INSTALLED_APPS` after the *base theme* and used `python manage.py startapp domain_eu` to generate the directory and manually created the `domain_eu/templates/pages/locations.html` file.

I then copied the locations page and assigned it to the EU site.

The page still renders with the locations template located in the *base theme* `domain_app/templates/pages/locations.html`

I've confirmed that the correct `SITE_ID` is set in the request.

**How do I get the page to render with the template in its corresponding theme/app directory based on the current `SITE_ID`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging into Mezzanine's code I figured out why my eu theme template was not rendering. The crucial bit of code can be found in `mezzanine/utils/sites.py`

```
def host_theme_path(request):
    """
    Returns the directory of the theme associated with the given host.
    """
    for (host, theme) in settings.HOST_THEMES:
        if host.lower() == request.get_host().split(":")[0].lower():
```

When I logged the result of `request.get_host()` I quickly realized the problem because it was `localhost` which obviously would not match any of the `HOST_THEMES` domains.

I had assumed that Mezzanine would use the session variable `site_id` as per [their documentation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/multi-tenancy.html) but apparently not down this particular template rendering code path.

**The solution** therefore was simply to edit my `/etc/hosts` file with the following:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.eu
```

Now when I visit `domain.eu/locations` it renders the template from the correct theme directory (in a local dev environment)